# Vue.js Component in list not applied

Tags: javascript, list, components, vue.js

This Component should show the div for every member data. Why does this not work?
Neither the component nor the 'repeater' is rendered, so it just shows the dirty html-code.

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <div class="table-responsive" id="vueTable">
            <div v-repeat="members" v-component="mm">
                @{{ prename }}
            </div>

    </div>
@endsection

@section('footer')
    <script src="/js/vue.js"></script>

    <script>
        var v = new Vue({
            el: '#vueTable',
            data: {
                members: [{
                    prename: 'Deniz',
                    lastname: 'Adanc',
                    ausstand: 0
                }]
            },
            components: {
                'mm': {
                    data: {aa: 'BBBBB'},
                    template: '<td><pre>@{{ $data | json }}</pre></td>'
                }
            }
        });




    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

may be because the DOM is not loaded?

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            //add js here...
        }, false);
```

Comment: If I change <div v-repeat="members" v-component="mm"> to <mm v-repeat="members"> it works. So I believe that the v-component attribute is not loaded, even though it's in the guide of vue.js.